# Text links go out of border block by zoom

Tags: html, css

I want to make block links which are located horizontally.
But with zoom site looks awful.
I am limiting the height of blocks but the text of the links bocomes bigger then the size of the blocks.
Text is visible outside of the blocks.

```
header {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(209, 208, 206, 0.6);
  height: 22vh;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
}

nav#menu {
  height: 3rem;
  position: relative;
  top: 14vh;
  max-height: 7vh;
}

nav#menu ul.left {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 5vh;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

nav#menu ul.left li {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

nav#menu ul li a {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav id="menu">
      <ul class="left">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

How can I fix that?
How to limit the font size of the links?
Or is it possible to limit zoom to make the site looks nice?

[The links looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM2zF.png)

Comment: first i recommend you don't use float left as it gets the element out of the normal flow of the document. use flexbox instead. Second, you use `rem` for the font size of the links. And also rem for height. Rem is used for font-size and it's relative to the font size of your body. You are making some confusions. I suggest you read more about units and flexbox

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove `height:100%;` from all elements.

Then on element `nav#menu ul li a` make `display:block;` to `display:inline-block;`

Couple of corrections in your CSS needed and some useless css need to be removed.

```
nav#menu ul.left {
  margin-left: 5vh;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}

nav#menu ul.left li {
  float: left;
}

nav#menu ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

Thanks